# ArrayList empty when accessed from separate thread although it is populated.

Tags: java

I have a simple Client/Server Application. I try to access the arraylist from UI but get an empty arraylist in return. I have tried every possible solution on internet but none has worked in my case.

Server.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
public static ArrayList<MyThread> clients = new ArrayList<MyThread>();

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(7777);
try {
while (true) {
Socket s1 = s.accept();
MyThread t = new MyThread(s1);
clients.add(t); // adds threads to an ArrayList
System.out.println(clients); // prints the ArrayList(It works and print all threads)
t.start(); //start the thread

}
} catch (SocketException e) {
System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
}
}
```

This is a MouseClickeed method in my UI class where I want to access the ArrayList in Server Class

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
try {

String s = textField.getText();
Client.ClientName = s; \\ gets the string entered and set it as Client Name
System.out.println(Server.clients); \\It's supposed to print Client ArrayList but instead it prints an empty List ([])


}

catch (NullPointerException e1) {
System.out.println("Error: " + e1);
}
}
});
```

Comment: have your client connected with the server yet?

Comment: Yes, already connected and added to the list. Thats for sure.

Comment: Please format your code - it's much harder to read when it's not indented. (And this clearly isn't your real code, as the slashes are backwards...)

Comment: What is not clear is how it is possible that `mouseClicked` can interact with the `Server` which is a console application.

Answer (score 0):

You're not just working with separate threads, you're working with different processes.

The Server process has it's own Server.class instance. The Client is launched in a different java process, it could use the same classes, but they will be different instances, even the static fields will be different in different processes.

If you need data from the Server in the Client, you need some sort of communication. You already have tcp/ip socket, so you could send the list via the socket.

Or you could use some distributed cache library if you want to use this pattern in a large application. E.g. [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org) or Terracotta DSO

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you try to use objects from Server application in client application with UI.

Server and client app are two different processes.
Server.clients is initialized with values in your server app, and isn't initialized in your client app.